# How to resolve Terraform "already exists." error for multiple resources while terraform apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Terraform fails on terraform apply, because of failure on "already exists" error.
I think this happened, because I manually deleted the tfstate and ddb md5 entries. Which created the whacky state of Terraform.

Now when I do init, plan and apply, I am getting quite a few errors as follows example:

```
Error: error creating SSM parameter: ParameterAlreadyExists: The parameter already exists. To overwrite this value, set the overwrite option in the request to true.
......

Error: error creating SSM parameter: ParameterAlreadyExists: The parameter already exists. To overwrite this value, set the overwrite option in the request to true.


Error: Error creating DB Parameter Group: DBParameterGroupAlreadyExists: Parameter group abc already exists
```

I have taken a look into the import option, but it's too messy.

Is there an easy or cleaner approach on tacking this?
Thank you, any advice will be helpful.

Comment: The state file is extremely important for TF operation. If you have a backup, restore it. Import on every resource is really your only option otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, it depends.

Each resource has it own functionalities, some allow you to overwrite existing resources and some don't.

For example, for ssm parameters, you can add a "overwrite" flag to the resource.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"

  overwrite = true
}
```

Official reference: [ssm_parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter#overwrite)

Now, a good way to avoid the issue of loosing tfstate is to store it in S3 in a bucket that has version control.

Comment: To expand a bit on the s3 state information here, to restore a state just select the version you want and upload that to the same key prefix. Then, if you use a lock table, you can drop this row's state hash, so it will update based on the new (old) state file.